# Use gsub remove all string before first white space in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a data frame like this:

```
name         weight
r apple         0.5
y pear          0.4
y cherry        0.1
g watermelon    5.0
pp grape        0.5
y apple pear    0.4
...  ...
```

I would like to remove all characters before the first white space in the name column.  Can anybody give me a favor? Thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
sub(".*? ", "", D$name)
```

#### Edit:

The pattern is looking for any character zero or more times (`.*`) up until the first space, and then capturing the one or more characters (`(.+)`) after that first space. The `?` after `.*` makes it "lazy" rather than "greedy" and is what makes it stop at the first space found.  So, the `.*?` matches everything before the first space, the space matches the first space found.

Comment: This works great, however, what does pattern command of the sub() mean?

Answer (score 8):

If `D` is your data frame, try

```
sub(".+? ", "", D$name)
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but for "y apple pear", it will give me only pear not the apple pear. I would like to remove everything before the first space not the last space. Thank you, though!

Comment: Make the pattern: "^[^ ]+ "

Comment: Try changing the pattern to `".+? "`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot how greedy regular expressions can be.  Thanks, BondedDust and CactusWoman for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution does not use gsub but it can be applied to a dataframe using a pipe operator `%>%`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# The data
df <- structure(list(name = c("r apple", "y pear", "y cherry", "g watermelon",
        "pp grape", "y apple pear"), weight = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 5.0, 0.5, 0.4)),
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Remove the first characters preceding a white space in the column "name"
df2 <- df %>% 
        mutate(name = str_replace(name, "^\\S* ", ""))
```

The regular expression `"^\\S* "` search for all characters from the beginning of the string until the first white space.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your data frame is called 'df'

```
library(reshape2)    
df$name = colsplit(df$name," ", names = c("chuck","name"))[,2]
```