# Remove everything before the last space

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I have a following string. I tried to remove all the strings before the last space but it seems I can't achieve it.

I tried to follow this post

[Use gsub remove all string before first white space in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767164/use-gsub-remove-all-string-before-first-white-space-in-r)

```
str <- c("Veni vidi vici")


gsub("\\s*","\\1",str)

"Venividivici"
```

What I want to have is only `"vici"` string left after removing everything before the last space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `gsub("\\s*","\\1",str)` code replaces each occurrence of 0 or more whitespaces with a reference to the capturing group #1 value (which is an empty string since you have not specified any capturing group in the pattern).

You want to match up to the last whitespace:

```
sub(".*\\s", "", str)
```

If you do not want to get a blank result in case your string has trailing whitespace, trim the string first:

```
sub(".*\\s", "", trimws(str))
```

Or, use a handy [`stri_extract_last_regex` from `stringi` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/0.2-5/topics/stri_extract_all_regex) with a simple `\S+` pattern (matching 1 or more non-whitespace chars):

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last_regex(str, "\\S+")
# => [1] "vici"
```

Note that `.*` matches any 0+ chars as many as possible (since `*` is a greedy quantifier and `.` in a TRE pattern matches any char including line break chars), and grabs the whole string at first. Then, backtracking starts since the regex engine needs to match a whitespace with `\s`. Yielding character by character from the end of the string, the regex engine stumbles on the last whitespace and calls it a day returning the match that is removed afterwards.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/nRmaWU) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/de08ut/2) online:

```
str <- c("Veni vidi vici")
gsub(".*\\s", "", str)
## => [1] "vici"
```

Also, you may want to see how backtracking works in the [regex debugger](https://regex101.com/r/de08ut/2/debugger):

[image]

Those red arrows show backtracking steps.