# Use gsub remove all string before first numeric character

Tags: r, string, gsub

[Use gsub remove all string before first white space in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767164/use-gsub-remove-all-string-before-first-white-space-in-r)

In this example, we try to remove everything before a space with `sub(".*? (.+)", "\\1", D$name)`. I'm looking for something really similar but I'm not really familiar with regex.

I want to delete everything before the first numeric character but without remove it

For example with:

`x <- c("lala65lolo","papa3hihi","george365meumeu")`

I want:

```
> "65lolo","3hihi", "365memeu"
```

Comment: Try `sub("[^0-9]+", "", x)`

Comment: @akrun I didn't want you to delete your answer. I just wanted you to be more careful. If the input string is "3dajdaj", your solution doesn't work, but can be easily generalized. Just that.

Comment: It is true that I was thinking whether I use `\\D+` or [^0-9]+`, but after I posted the answer, a a similar answer got posted.  So, I thought to keep it and then you commented.  Anyway, it is okay

Comment: Sorry, after reflexion my example was a little bit simplist ! Don't worry, thank for your help, i have my answer !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
> x <- c("lala65lolo","papa3hihi","george365meumeu")
> sub("^\\D+", "", x)
[1] "65lolo"    "3hihi"     "365meumeu"
```

Or, to make sure there is a digit:

```
sub("^\\D+(\\d)", "\\1", x)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\\D+` - one or more chars other than digit
- `(\\d)` - Capturing group 1: a digit (the `\1` in the replacement pattern restores the digit captured in this group).

In a similar way, you may achieve the following:

- `sub("^\\s+", "", x)` - remove all text up to the first non-whitespace char
- `sub("^\\W+", "", x)` - remove all text up to the first word char
- `sub("^[^-]+", "", x)` - remove all text up to the first hyphen (if there is any), etc.

Answer (score 9):

In R 3.6 (currently the R devel version) onwards `trimws` has a new `whitespace` argument which can be used to specify what is regarded as whitespace -- in this case any non-digit character:

```
trimws(x, "left", "\\D")
## [1] "65lolo"    "3hihi"     "365meumeu"
```

Comment: Just be careful this method cannot make sure there is a digit. 
```trimws("abc", "left", "\\D") returns ""```
But if there is a digit it works well.