# Replace the first occurrence of a character within a string in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I am working with lots of strings. I realized I can read them using `read.table()` but I have to clean them beforehand.

I have this general structure:

```
Request(123): \n Element1: 123123 \n Element2: 456456
```

I want to remove only the first time the semicolon `:` appears, but not the remaining ones.

```
Request(123) \n Element1: 123123 \n Element2: 456456
```

Let the first string be stored in `test`. After reading a couple of threads, I tried `.*`:

```
gsub(pattern = ".*:", replacement = "", x = test)
```

I know you can use a question mark to [make the searching "lazy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767164/use-gsub-remove-all-string-before-first-white-space-in-r), but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `sub(":", "", test, fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `g` in `gsub` stands for *global*, indicating that it will match all occurrences. If you use `sub` instead of `gsub`, only the first occurrence will be matched and replaced. See `?gsub` for details, in the *Description*:

> `sub` and `gsub` perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively.

And, if you only want to replace the colon, your pattern should just be `":"`, `".*:"` will match and replace everything up through the last colon. If you want to replace everything up through the first colon, using `sub` and `?` to make `*` not greedy will work.

```
x = "Request(123): \n Element1: 123123 \n Element2: 456456"

## match everything up through last colon
sub(".*:", "", x)
# [1] " 456456"

## not greedy, match everything up through first colon
sub(".*?:", "", x)
# [1] " \n Element1: 123123 \n Element2: 456456"

## match first colon only
## since we don't need regex here, fixed = TRUE will speed things up
sub(":", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "Request(123) \n Element1: 123123 \n Element2: 456456"

## compare to gsub, match every colon
gsub(":", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "Request(123) \n Element1 123123 \n Element2 456456"
```