# Substitute up until first - ("dash") with regex

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Given the following string:

```
Test <- c("123 - Test1", "1234 - Test2", "123 - 45 - Test3")
```

When I use `gsub` as below with very basic regex

```
gsub(".*- ", "", Test)
```

I get the following output:

```
"Test1" "Test2" "Test3"
```

How can I change my regex to only substitute up until the first `-` to get the following result:

```
"Test1" "Test2" "45 - Test3"
```

I know regex is 'greedy' so I am looking for a way to overcome this greediness.

Comment: `sub(".*?- ", "", Test)`, or `"^[^-]*- "`. Note that `sub` will remove the first occurrence only, `gsub` removes all. Also, see [the R related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767164/use-gsub-remove-all-string-before-first-white-space-in-r) where you just need to use the hyphen.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Should I remove this question because it is a duplicate?

Comment: No need to remove it. Just mind that [`greedy` and `lazy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) are too well-known terms in the regex world.